# Command line equivalent to 'Build Source Package' in RStudio

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2

I am aware of `R CMD build package_name` which can be run from the terminal. However, this doesn't appear to do the same thing as Build -> Build Source Package in RStudio. My (crude) test has been to make changes and building with the terminal command, but the changes don't go through to the `package_name_0.1.0.tar.gz` file, whereas when using RStudio they do.

Is there a command line equivalent of doing Build -> Build Source Package from RStudio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better late than never...

Since we can see the (R) code that is executed when we select 'Build Source Package' from the RStudio menu, that same R code can be run from terminal

In terminal, from inside the root of the package:

```bash
R -e "devtools::document(roclets = c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace')); devtools::build()"
```

Or case anyone arrives here after the actual R code:

```r
devtools::document(roclets = c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace'))
devtools::build()
```